# exceptions across module boundaries, needs -fPIC?

Tags: c++, g++, elf

Im throwing an exeception from a shared library and catching it in another so. I control all source code so it should be OK and I use g++4.4.5. First the following code didnt work:

```
try
  {
// do something that throws tags::out_of_range in the other shared lib
  }
catch(const tags::out_of_range& e)
  {
cout << "out_of_range " << typeid(tags::out_of_range()).name() << endl;
cout << "out of range exception " << typeid(e).name() << endl;
  }
catch (const exception& e2)
  {
cout << "out_of_range " << typeid(tags::out_of_range()).name() << endl;
cout << "other exception " << typeid(e2).name() << endl;
  }
```

I always ended up catching only a std::exception. Printing the typeid().name() as seen in the code gave the possible explanation:

> out_of_range  FN4tags12out_of_rangeEvE
>
> other exception  N4tags12out_of_rangeE

We can see the names dont match, and if I understood it correctly, when the classes are in different modules the names are actually string compared for dynamic casting.

So somewhere I then read try with adding -fPIC, and suddenly it worked (meaning i caught an out_of_range exception), although printing the names still give the same result. I thought position independent code didnt matter any longer, and looking in the g++ man pages about -fPIC:

> "This option makes a difference on the m68k, PowerPC and SPARC"

And I use an x86-64. I really dont see how code positioning could make any difference in this case? Also, if the typeid names are string compared I thought I would still end up in the std::exception clause, as they are still different even with -fPIC?

So the question: Why does -fPIC make any difference?

Comment: See the first comment on: http://www.technovelty.org/code/c/amd64-pic.html (No affiliation, it's just by far the clearest explanation of PIC I've seen online)

Comment: Thanks, Im still not sure I understand whats happening in my case though. I mean in both cases the instruction pointer must be correct as the typeid info is identical in both cases?

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce this bug. How are you loading the third party library? At runtime with `dlopen()` or linking it in at compile time?